# Area in Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, area

[image: limacon]

The graph of $$r=24\cos(\theta)-12$$ is a limacon. The region between its inner and outer loops is shaded in the figure. 
That shaded region has area ____________ square units.

I don't know how to approach this question I have for homework. I would really appreciate the help in solving this question.

Comment: You have really no idea? Not even the faintest one? Maybe if you explain what your toughts are we could evaluate your knowledge and answer accordingly. (PS: nice picture :-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.  Your basic area formula in polar coordinates is
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_\alpha^\beta r^2\,d\theta\ .$$
You need to do the following.

1. Find the $\theta$ values which give you the "outer" part of the curve.  (Hint: what $\theta$ values give $r=0$?)
2. Apply the above integration formula.  This will give the area inside the outer curve, that is, the shaded area plus the little unshaded area.
3. Repeat (1) and (2) for the "inner" part of the curve.  This will give the little unshaded area.
4. Subtract (3) from (2).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is extremely helpful!